# Can I write this $|x|=y\implies \pm x=y$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

$$|x|=y...(i)$$

$$\implies \pm x=y...(ii)$$

Can I write this? If not, what line can follow (i) that doesn't include a $||$ but includes a $\pm$?

I ask this because in [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ry8hyqsymp), the graphs of $|x|=y$ and that of $x=y$ & $x=-y$ aren't the same. The graphs of $x=y$ & $x=-y$ contain extra values. So, I figured that (ii) can't follow (i). Am I correct?

Comment: Other ways to write it could be $\,\sqrt{x^2}=y\,$ or $\,x^2=y^2\,$. That's assuming the question asks about the one-way implication $\implies$ (as posted), not about a two-way equivalence $\iff$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing $y=\pm x$ is a shorthand for "$y=x$ or $y=-x$".

It is true that $|x|=y\implies y=\pm x$.

But the other direction is false. The condition $y=\pm x$ may be met when $y$ is a negative number. And then it would be impossible for $|x|=y$.

This is precisely why the two Desmos graphs don't match. The two relations are not equivalent. It's only the case that one relation implies the other, so one graph is a subset of the other graph.

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not true.

$$|x|=y\require{cancel}\hspace{1em} \cancel{\hspace{-1em}{\implies}\hspace{-1em}}\hspace{1em} y=±x$$

Because, if $x<0$ (or $x>0$) then you get

$$y=±(-x)=±x, ~x>0~\text{or} \\ y=±x, ~x>0$$

But, this is false. Because, $y≥0$ must be.

The correct result can be considered as follows:

$$|x|=y,y≥0\iff x=±y$$

Also, we can write

$$|x|=y\implies y=-x~\text{if}~x<0$$

and

$$|x|=y\implies y=x~\text{if}~x≥0.$$

---

In this answer, the definition of $±$ means  $x ~~\text{«and»}-x.$